# How to launch app automatically after bundling? (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I have three product flavors: dev, staging, and prod.

And when I connect the actual phone and run it,
I get the error "Activity class {} does not exist".

Bundling doesn't fail, but the app doesn't run automatically, how do I fix it?

build.gradle

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        devDebug: "env/.env.development",
        devrelease: "env/.env.development",
        stagingDebug: "env/.env.staging",
        stagingrelease: "env/.env.staging",
        prodDebug: "env/.env.production",
        prodrelease: "env/.env.production",
        anothercustombuild: ".env.local",
]
```

package.json

```
"android:dev": "react-native run-android --mode=devDebug",
    "android:stg": "react-native run-android --mode=stagingDebug",
    "android:prd": "react-native run-android --mode=prodrelease",
```

dev version will launched